# Fetching 1000 + records quikly

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

Am using java as language,Spring Mvc and Hibernate as Frameworks,mysql as database.

I have 1000 records to show.its taking long time to fetch 1000+ records in single request.so ,i want to fetch 25 records first ,then next 25 records,then next 25 records like that.how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code.

Comment: implement pagination, happy coding !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working Fine with my little change

For First 25 Result
select * from table limit 0,25
For this query i will Get 1 to 25 Records

second 25 Result
select * from table limit 25,25
For this query i will Get 26 to 50 Records

next 25 Result
for Example if page is 3
as per your calculation (every request calculate (page number * 25);)
(3*25)=75
select * from table limit 75,25
For this query i will Get 75 to 100 Records
But Actucally i need 3rd 25 Records which is 51 to 75

so I Changed calculation like this
every request calculate (page number -1  * 25)

if page is 3 then ((3-1) *25) =(2*25)=50
select * from table limit 50,25
For this query i will Get 51 to 75 Records .which is i Wanted......

Answer (score 0):

Use Query with limit option, with pagination concept
for example

```
select * from table limit 0,25
```

second 25 result

```
select * from table limit 25,25
```

every request calculate (page number * 25);

if page is 20 then 20*25

```
 select * from table limit 500,25
```